# C++ Calling function inside another function that uses references and parameters

Tags: c++, c, function, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm programming at Arduino IDE (that uses basically C++) and I'm in trouble to call a function inside another. The part of code is below:

```
unsigned long int deslocamento (char sentido, byte &cont, const int pino, unsigned long int posicaoA)
{
  byte leitura;
  unsigned int deltaposicao;

  leitura = digitalRead(pino);

  if ((leitura == HIGH) && (cont == 0))
  {
    cont = 1;
  }

  if ((leitura == LOW) && (cont == 1))
  {
    cont = 0;

    deltaposicao++;
  }

  if (sentido == 'F')
  {
    posicaoA += deltaposicao;
  }

  else
  {
    posicaoA -= deltaposicao;
  }

  return posicaoA;
}

void zeramento (unsigned long int posicaoA)
{
  byte pwm = 255;
  char sentido = 'R';

  byte fator;

  fator = fatorcorrecaoP (pwm);

  while (posicaoA != 0)
  {
    posicaoA = deslocamento (sentido, cont, pinencoder, posicaoA);

    posicaoA -= fator;

    comando (sentido, pwm);
  }
}
```

On function "void zeramento" should I declare as inputs all the inputs (parameters) that function "unsigned long int deslocamento" uses too or have an easier and shorter (or maybe a more efficient in therms of memory optimization) way to do that? For example, should I declare as "void zeramento(posicaoA, sentido, &cont, pinecoder)"?

Thanks for all and sorry for any problem. I'm new here and still learning English.

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: I omitted the rest of code, but I'll try to describe it at my best. It's a code for ATMEGA that operates a machine of cutting. The machine have many inputs for user, as speed and lenght of operation. It goes to determined position, and so goes back. It has many other functions, like memory handling. The first one ("deslocamento") of both determine, based on direction of move, last position and read of an encoder sensor, the actual position of the machine. The second is executed only at the start and its for to move the machine to zero position, based on which position it was when turned on.

Comment: Why? Since posicaoA refers to last position and the function "deslocamento" updates posicaoA based on how much of distance was covered.

Comment: I noticed it's  a global variable, try to avoid using them.

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's used on mostly of functions. That's why it's global.

Comment: That's not a good reason, pass it as a parameter.

Comment: does using a global variable inside a namespace solve your problem? The namespace hides it from the rest of the application.

Comment: @Arashium The problem with globals is that it is shared mutable state, not that the scope is global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. For a shorter code, I'll just call your functions `funcA` and `funcB` and the parameters `par1` and `par2`.

You can do either

```
void funcA(int par1, int par2)
{ ... use par1 and par2 ... }

void funcB(int par1, int par2)
{
    ...
    funcA(par1, par2);
    ...
}
```

or

```
int global_par1;
int global_par2;

void funcA(int par1, int par2)
{ ... use par1 and par2 ... }

void funcB()
{
    ...
    funcA(global_par1, global_par2);
    ...
}
```

In the first case you only use local variables, while in the second you use global ones.

The difference is that in the global case (please call them differently in `funcA` and `funcB`, since there could be readability issues) the variables are unique for the whole program (i.e. if you modify them in the `main` you will modify them even in the functions), while in the local case you are just working on a local copy of them.

In my opinion, since these variables identify the position (which is unique) I'd go with a fully global solution, i.e.

```
int global_par1;
int global_par2;

void funcA()
{ .. use global_par1 and global_par2.. }

void funcB()
{
    ...
    funcA();
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, as I said, should I declare it as
     void zeramento(posicaoA, sentido, &cont, pinecoder)
?

I wanted to avoid from it, since I've already have to specify all this parameters to the function deslocamento. It looks ambiguous to me, so I thought it ll have a more appropriated way

Comment: if you prefer the local variables version, yes. Or better, I'd call it `void zeramento (char sentido, byte &cont, const int pino, unsigned long int posicaoA)` (`posicaoA` at the end, just to have the same fingerprint for both functions - it's more readable)

Comment: You are welcome, but... What do you mean by "not precisely as i wanted"? ;)